# How is this equality symbol different from a regular equality (=) symbol?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I encountered the following equality symbol in a [paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_iccv_2013/html/Engel_Semi-dense_Visual_Odometry_2013_ICCV_paper.html) (page 4, Eq 4). I am not sure how it is different from a regular equality (=) symbol.

[image]

**What does this symbol mean? And how can I write it in latex?**

Comment: meaning of the mathematics is off topic here sorry, a tex question of how to typeset that would be on topic. (If I knew the meaning I'd have mentioned it here)

Comment: Off topic: maybe it is only to explain from where that equality comes. Look for some equation named as `(!)`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your input. Since you mentioned, I feel interested in how one would go about writing that symbol.

Comment: @Sigur I have flagged the post for migration. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

OP comments: "I feel interested in how one would go about writing that symbol"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\bangequal{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{1pt}{=}{\scriptstyle!}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \bangequal b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get the particularly ugly version where the `!` is underlined...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\bangequal{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{=}{\underline{\scriptstyle!}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \bangequal b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I don't know why but the image posted appears to have an underlined `!` above `=`. Ugly.

Comment: @Sigur I'll look to provide that ugly alternative as an...alternative.

Comment: Oh nooo, please don't reproduce that... lol

Comment: @Sigur My bad. It had underlined + highlighted in my draft, I removed the highlight but the underline remained.  It's not there in the original paper.

Comment: @Sigur Too late.....

Comment: @Sigur Steven only needs to wrap `\textcolor{white}{...}` around it, then it is not too bad. ;-)